# How can I compute a running sum?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

To get a running sum in column $2, row i of all entries in column $1 from the first row @1 up to and including row i,

```
| 1.01 |  |
| 2.02 |  |
| 4.04 |  |
```

the tedious solution is to write (for three rows)

```
| 1.01 | 1.01 |
| 2.02 | 3.03 |
| 4.04 | 7.07 |
#+TBLFM: @1$2=vsum(@1$1..@1$1)::@2$2=vsum(@1$1..@2$1)::@3$2=vsum(@1$1..@3$1)
```

How can I capture `@i$2=vsum(@1$1..@i$1)`, for any number of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works if you manually add the value for the first row:

```
| 1.01 | 1.01 |
| 2.02 |      |
| 4.04 |      |
#+TBLFM: @2$2..@>$2=$1+@-1
```

It's using a "range formula". `@>` means "the last row", `@-1` is the "previous row".

Another possibility is to add an empty row and a hline. Then you run <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> without filling in any values:

```
|      |      |
|------+------|
| 1.01 |      |
| 2.02 |      |
| 4.04 |      |
#+TBLFM: $2=@-1+$1
```